# Apple style popup animation / easing?

Tags: css, animation

I want to recreate the apple popup/alert's (iOS) animation and easing in js/css. Which easing function is it using? Is there any existing code that describes the animation?

Comment: Popup/alert on iOS? Or on OS X?

Comment: Could you post a link with a demonstration of the desired effect. I think that not anyone knows what apple or orange effect you are talking about. Also showing your code and the progress you've made so far might be helpful as well as the particular problems you've encountered with it.

Comment: Are you referring to the http://growl.info/ style of notifications?

Comment: @alecgorge sorry, meant on iOS

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I don't have a link, please look on your iOS device. I think the easing function's something out easeOutBounce, but like some confirmation on that. The animation's actually rather simple, just a scaling. I'm fairly certain now it could just be done with css3 and don't need javascript

Comment: @Harry, I don't have an iOS device for Christ Sake :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check out various easing functions (and how to implement them with CSS/SCSS/JavaScript) here https://easings.net/

[image]

You can also check out Lea Verou's cubic-bezier previewer at http://cubic-bezier.com/ to see what best suits your desired `timing-function`

Comment: Providing link as a answer i guess leads to incomplete solution as in way links gets expired which now happened as your above link is not working anymore